# How to check if the content is plain text or not?

Tags: java, html, parsing, validation, text

I have a plain text area where I accept only plain text from users. I want to make sure that users do not put any markup in the text area. I also assume that users can post in different languages. So, what is the best approach to validate the content both at the server side (using java) and at the client side (using jquery).

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Update: I am sorry if the question wasn't clear enough. To make it simple, this is what I want to do - I let users type text in the textarea (no rich text box here). For each double new line in the text area i want to show a paragraph in the HTML page. How do I do that correctly?

Comment: Why? You can/should just HTMLEncode any output based on this input.

Comment: What do you understand by "plain text"? HTML is also plain text when it's interpreted as such. Maybe you just want to escape any special HTML characters from the user input so that they won't be interpreted as HTML when you display them in the browser?

Comment: well when i say plain text, i mean that i do not expect users to supply any markup tags etc. I plan to convert the plain text into a simple HTML so that its displayed correctly in the webpage: 
EG: The original text would be like "This is a simple line\n\n and I and now in the second paragraph" and i convert it to "<p>This is a simple line</p><p>and I and now in the second paragraph</p>" Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes little sense to validate user input on HTML content. You can just escape HTML when redisplaying this user input on the webpage. Since you mentioned that you're using Java on the server side and thus you're likely using JSP as view technology, it's good to know that you can use the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<c:out>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) tag and [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) function to escape HTML before printing to output.

E.g. when redisplaying user-controlled input:

```
<c:out value="${somebean.sometext}" />
```

or when redisplaying user-submitted request parameter:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.foo)}" />
```

This way for example `<script>alert('xss')</script>` will be printed to HTML output as `&lt;script&gt;alert(&#39;xss&#39;)&lt;/script&gt;` and thus be displayed in HTML literally as the enduser typed in itself.

---

If you *really* insist to validate this, you could eventually grab a HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) for this.

```
String text = request.getParameter("text");

if (!text.equals(Jsoup.parse(text).text())) {
    // There was HTML in the text.
}
```

---

**Update** as per the comments you *actually* want to sanitize the input against a HTML whitelist to remove potential malicious tags. You can do this with Jsoup as well, see also [this page](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer).

```
String sanitized = Jsoup.clean(text, Whitelist.basic());
```

The allowed elements of `Whitelist#basic()` is specified in the [API documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html#basic%28%29).

Comment: I cannot escape the HTML at the JSP coz I plan to show text as paragraphs in HTML page. So if my text was like this "<p>Paragraph one</p><p>Paragraph two</p>", using the escape function will show the whole text in one line. Do u think I have any other alternative so that I can correctly show the paragraphs.

Comment: Ah your **concrete** question is thus to remove malicious XSS-attack-sensitive tags from user-controlled HTML input with help of a whitelist? You can do this with Jsoup as well, see answer update.

Comment: As per your question update, to redisplay user-entered newlines in textarea, just string-replace `\n` by `<p>` or apply CSS `white-space:pre;` on the containing element. (please note that this starts to get pretty confusing, I have basically given three different answers to three completely different problems; you should try to get the basic concepts straight first before asking a question and ask a new question for every individual problem)

Answer (score 0):

If it's HTML markup you want to prevent, you could use a regular expression to throw an error if it sees a chevron (<)

Comment: Which will also prevent users typing smilies such as `<3` or expressions such as `3 < 4`

Comment: Do you want to prevent submission of the text area if it contains HTML markup, or just ensure it isn't parsed as HTML once it's been grabbed?